# VMWare Physical CPU to vCPU

Tags: sql-server, vmware-esxi, vcpu

We have VMWare hosts with 2 cpus each (that are hyperthreading). We freed up some licensing (2 core licenses) for SQL server and want to upgrade from 4 to 6 cores.

From my understanding, for SQL Server, you want even number of cores per socket. This leads to the SQL best practice of 3 sockets @ 2 cores each for the VM.

Are there performance implications or concerns to/with VMWare by allocating 3 vSockets on a 2 socket host?

Comment: Could you please share us with CPU specifics you have? Also, you might find the answer at VMware best practices: http://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

Comment: Intel E5-2260's. The issue is actually resolved. Per Brent Ozar's (BDA gurus) team, the best option is single socket, 6 core.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with some SQL Server experts, the best option was 1 socket, 6 cores.

Comment: Did the experts include any logical reasons for this best option?